# (Wordpress) Hide posts from homepage using custom fields

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hide, posts

I was just wondering if it's possible to hide posts from the homepage via custom fields. 
I'm using a plugin called WP Hide Post to hide specific posts from the homepage, but curious if it could be done without relying on the plugin. Is there a way to use the function via "Custom Fields"? What would be the name to call the function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use CSS to hide the the post: http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-embed-css-in-your-posts-with-a-custom-field

Cya